# Inconsistencies between Storyboard and xib in view appearance process

Tags: cocoa-touch, storyboard

I don't understand when it's safe to ask about the frame of a `UIView` during the view appearance chain and/or the differences related to that with Storyboard vs a traditional xib.

I created two different, very simple single `UIViewController` projects in Xcode 4.5.1; in the first I used the standard single view template with a xib and in the second I used Storyboard. The source code for `ViewController.m` – identical for both projects – is given below. In IB I dragged in a `UIScrollView` and wired it appropriately to my controller outlet.

As you'll note in the source, I'm logging out the frame of my scroll view at different points in the view appearance chain. I don't understand why they are different and/or when I can safely query the UIScrollView frame since it's (0,0) in `viewDidLoad`.

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"viewWillLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);    
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
@end
```

### Results with xib

```
2012-10-23 11:49:48.316 ScrollTest[83262:c07] viewDidLoad scrollView.frame = (320,548)
2012-10-23 11:49:48.318 ScrollTest[83262:c07] viewWillAppear scrollView.frame = (320,548)
2012-10-23 11:49:48.321 ScrollTest[83262:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (320,548)
2012-10-23 11:49:48.328 ScrollTest[83262:c07] viewDidAppear scrollView.frame = (320,460)
```

### Results with Storyboard

```
2012-10-23 11:49:58.762 ScrollTestStoryboard[83308:c07] viewDidLoad scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 11:49:58.763 ScrollTestStoryboard[83308:c07] viewWillAppear scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 11:49:58.765 ScrollTestStoryboard[83308:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 11:49:58.772 ScrollTestStoryboard[83308:c07] viewDidAppear scrollView.frame = (320,460)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Wish I'd seen about 20 minutes ago. Below is updated source code and log output.

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"viewWillLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear scrollView.frame = (%3.0f,%3.0f)",self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
@end
```

### Storyboard output

```
2012-10-23 12:12:35.597 ScrollTestStoryboard[87593:c07] viewDidLoad scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 12:12:35.599 ScrollTestStoryboard[87593:c07] viewWillAppear scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 12:12:35.601 ScrollTestStoryboard[87593:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (  0,  0)
2012-10-23 12:12:35.602 ScrollTestStoryboard[87593:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews scrollView.frame = (320,460)
2012-10-23 12:12:35.609 ScrollTestStoryboard[87593:c07] viewDidAppear scrollView.frame = (320,460)
```